# How to sort a multidimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I generally post the code I have so far, but I have nothing on this one... :(

How would I go about re-ordering the following array so that I can base it on the value in the 'percentage' key, either low-to-high or high-to-low?

```
var data = [{
    "id": "q1",
    "question": "blah blah blah",
    "percentage": "32"
}, {
    "id": "q2",
    "question": "blah blah blah",
    "percentage": "23"
}, {
    "id": "q3",
    "question": "blah blah blah",
    "percentage": "11"
}, {
    "id": "q4",
    "question": "blah blah blah",
    "percentage": "3"
}, {
    "id": "q5",
    "question": "blah blah blah",
    "percentage": "6"
}]
```

Comment: That's not a multidimensional array. It's an array of objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit of correction, it's not a multidimensional array, it's an array of objects, you most likely mixed up the naming from `PHP`, for your question, use the optional function argument of [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to define your own sorting order.

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.percentage - b.percentage;
})

// sorted data, no need to do data = data.sort(...);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cEfRd/

Answer (score 4):

Sorter generator, generalizing https://stackoverflow.com/users/135448/siganteng answer so that it works on any property

```
function  createSorter(propName) {
    return function (a,b) {
        // The following won't work for strings
        // return a[propName] - b[propName];
        var aVal = a[propName], bVal = b[propName] ;
        return aVal > bVal ? 1 : (aVal < bVal ?  - 1 : 0);

    };
}
data.sort(createSorter('percentage'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data.sort(function(a,b){return a.percentage - b.percentage});
```

The [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).